# Direction of acceleration in elliptical path

Tags: kinematics, orbital-motion, planets

The $x$ and $y$ coordinates of a particle moving in a plane are given by:
$$x(t)=a\cos(pt)$$  $$y(t)=b\sin(pt),$$
where $a$ , $b(<a)$, and $p$ are positive constants of appropriate dimensions and $t$ is time.

I know this is the equation of ellipse. To find acceleration vector I wrote the position vector $\vec{r}$ and differentiated it twice to find that acceleration vector is directed towards the centre.

But when planets are revolving in elliptical path acceleration vector is towards focus. Then why the acceleration of planets is not towards centre?

Comment: I think it is because in case of planets paramteric angle of ellipse is not varying as wt it is a complicated function of t

Comment: Did you include the fact that the $\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$ unit vectors are varying with time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Keplerian behavior of the planets (elliptical orbits with the Sun at one focus) is a consequence of the fact that the force on them is proportional to $1/r^2$.  If the force behaves in a different way, you get a different orbit.

In particular, you found that the acceleration points towards the center, or
$$
\vec{a} = - \omega^2 \vec{r}
$$
which then implies that $\vec{F} = - m \omega^2 \vec{r}$.  Thus, in this case the magnitude of the force on the object is proportional to $r$, not $1/r^2$, and we should not expect Keplerian orbits.  In fact, this would be the force exerted on a 2D harmonic oscillator with stiffness $k = m \omega^2$ in each direction.  The fact that both cases ($F \propto 1/r^2$ and $F \propto r$) generally yield elliptical orbits is, I suspect, a coincidence.

You didn't ask but I'm telling you anyways:  [it can be shown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem) that these two cases  are the only central force laws for which all orbits form closed loops.  For other cases, most orbits do not close on themselves;  after going $2\pi$ around the center, they do not generally return to the same location in space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i agree with saksham, actually in planetary motion w (omega) (here p) is not constant if that was the case Kepler's third law would not work. Omega is actually oscillating with time